# Conditional calculation in python

Tags: python, numpy, conditional-statements

I'm attempting to use my own modified version of the `logsumexp()` from here: 
https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.14.0/scipy/misc/common.py#L18

On line 85, is this calculation:

```
out = log(sum(exp(a - a_max), axis=0))
```

But I have a threshold and I don't want `a - a_max` to exceed that threshold.
Is there a way to do a conditional calculation, which would allow the subtraction to take place only if the difference isn't less than the threshold.
So something like:

```
out = log(sum(exp( (a - a_max < threshold) ? threshold : a - a_max), axis = 0))
```

Comment: You could check `a` against `threshold + a_max`, i.e. a modified threshold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a conditional inline statement in Python:

```
Value1 if Condition else Value2
```

Your formula transforms to:

```
out = log(sum(exp(threshold if a - a_max < threshold else a - a_max), axis = 0))
```

Comment: I'm getting this error:
` out = log(sum(exp(threshold if a - a_max < threshold else a - a_max), axis=0))
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

Comment: Can you give me some sample data? What data types are each variable?

Comment: The thread is old, but for completeness sake: the problem is that the condition tries to evaluate the whole condition array, not per index. Meaning, for each index it does “if condition_array“, instead of “if condition_array[0]“, then “if condition_array[1]„ ..., see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18397869/placing-a-condition-while-calculating-using-numpy-array

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
out = log(sum(exp( threshold if a - a_max < threshold else a - a_max), axis = 0))
```